# Javascript adding class to paragraph if paragraph contains checkbox

Tags: javascript, css

So, I am trying to add a class to a paragraph only if the paragraph contains a checkbox. Here is my code (faulty obviously).

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('p').each(function(){
var p = element.parentNode;
if ( $(this).val() != '') 
if ( $(this).val().indexOf('checkbox')>=0) 
{
p.className = p.className + "stylename";
} 
else {alert ('the if function works');}  // test
}
);})
```

Answer (score 2):

Since that seems to be jQuery...

```
$("p:has(:checkbox)").addClass("stylename");
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/LMB7L/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest selecting the relevant input, and then styling its ancestor:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').closest('p').addClass('stylename');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LMB7L/1/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: +1 because in spite of my answer, I'm a bit of a bigot when it comes to using non-standard selectors. The valid selectors are the way to go IMO, even if it's a tiny bit longer. :-)

Comment: @DavidThomas, I do not want to abuse of your help, but it seems so easy for you. How about if I wanted to style differently the paragraph if the box is checked or not? (in the Fiddle?) I am not not a programmer, so it is not simple for me. I am styling checkboxes and I found a good solution, but my paragraphs need to have a class. The most simple solution for styling checkboxes I ever encoutered!!!